# Add class when page loads

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the HTML code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<div class="logo"> 
   <a href="http://www.afterquote.com/"> <img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" /></a>
</div>
<!--logo--> 
</div>
<!--content--> 
</div>
<!--container-->

CSS

.logo.animated {
    border-radius: 50%;
transform: rotate(720deg);
}
.logo {
    height: 80px;
margin: 0 auto;
transition: all 1s ease 0s;
width: 80px;
}
.logo img {
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

i want to load the .logo.animated class when the page is loaded. please share the jquery code for the same.

Comment: You need to use `addClass()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)** as well as wrapping your code inside `$(window).load(function() {...});`:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.logo').addClass('animated');
});
```

Comment: +1 However seems the OP is looking for `$(window).load()` because of `when the page is loaded`.

Comment: You're really fast in answering, no room remains for the others :)

Comment: Thanks. it make sense. unfortunately the animation is not working after the page load :(

Answer (score 0):

you can do using this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.logo').addClass('animated');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have image on your page, you would want to wait for the image to be loaded (*otherwise you will see animation even if image is not loaded*) -
In that case you could use

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.logo').addClass('animated');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below:

either :

```
$(function() {
$('.logo').addClass('animated');
});
```

Or:

```
window.load(function(){
$('.logo').addClass('animated');
})
```